# SQL sum and divide by number of results

Tags: php, sql, divide

Can't get it to work... this is what I got so far:

```
SELECT CardCode, (sum(DocRate) DocRate/DocRate.Length)
FROM OPCH
WHERE DocRate > 1
  AND DocStatus = 'O'
  AND DocDate >= '20140101'
GROUP BY CardCode
```

Trying to get the sum of DocRate (which is diffrent each row) and divide it with number of rows (to get an average).

This isn't working.

Comment: "This isn't working." is never good. Specify what isn't working, errors, warnings, results, etc.

Comment: `sum(DocRate)/count(DocRate)` or simply `avg(DocRate)`

Comment: To get an average use.. average :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well easy enough, found the solution.
Using `AVG()`.

My code:

```
SELECT CardCode,
       avg(DocRate) DocRate
FROM OPCH
WHERE DocRate > 1
  AND DocStatus = 'O'
  AND DocDate >= '20140101'
GROUP BY CardCode
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using sub query.

```
SELECT CardCode, (DocRate/length)
FROM
  (SELECT CardCode,sum(DocRate) DocRate, sum (DocRate.Length) length
FROM OPCH
WHERE DocRate > 1
  AND DocStatus = 'O'
  AND DocDate >= '20140101'
GROUP BY CardCode) doc
GROUP BY CardCode
```

Comment: Found the solution already, still tried yours but it doesn't work.

Comment: It should work actually nothing complex here... what is the error...if its not ignore the solution

Comment: @Nir Tzezana... understood the problem...updated my answer... now it will work...give it a try

Comment: from Mssql server: 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: I apologize for asking you again and again to use the solution.... but this time changed and should work